# using Grok to skip parts of message or logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have just started using grok for logstash and I am trying to parse my log file using grok filter. 
My logline is something like below

> 03-30-2017 13:26:13 [00089] TIMER XXX.TimerLog: entType [organization], queueType [output], memRecno = 446323718, audRecno = 2595542711, elapsed time = 998ms

I want to capture only the initial date/time stamp, `entType [organization]`,  and `elapsed time = 998ms`.

However, it looks like I have to match pattern for every word and number in the line. Is there a way I can skip it ? I tried to look everywhere but couldn't find anything. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you *tried* just bypassing things you don't care about with `(?:.*)`? Grok syntax is just context-aware nested regex support; all the usual approaches apply.

Answer (score 9):

As per Charles Duffy's comment.

There are 2 ways of doing this:
The `GREEDYDATA` way `(?:.*)`:

```
grok {
  match => {"message" => "^%{DATE_US:dte}\s*%{TIME:tme}\s*\[%{GREEDYDATA}elapsed time\s*=\s*%{BASE10NUM}"
}
```

Or, telling it to ignore a match and look for the next one in the list.

```
grok {
  break_on_match => false
  match => { "message" => "^%{DATE_US:dte}\s*%{TIME:tme}\s*\[" }
  match => { "message" => "elapsed time\s*=\s*%{BASE10NUM:elapsedTime}"
}
```

You can then rejoin the date & time into a single field and convert it to a timestamp.

Answer (score 6):

As **Charles Duffy** suggested, you can simply bypass data you don't need.

You can use `.*` to do that.

Following will produce the output you want,

```
%{DATE_US:dateTime}.*entType\s*\[%{WORD:org}\].*elapsed time\s*=\s*%{BASE10NUM}
```

**Explanation:**

- `\s*` matches space character.
- `\[` is bypassing `[` character.
- `%{WORD:org}` defines a word boundary and place it in a new field `org`

**Outputs**

```
{
  "dateTime": [
    [
      "03-30-2017"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "03"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "30"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2017"
    ]
  ],
  "org": [
    [
      "organization"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "998"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[Click for a list of all available grok patterns](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns)